# Account record does not get created

Tags: create-records

I followed instructions on "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm" to insert a new account record. I get no errors, but the account record does not get created. When I tried same in .Net I see that the response I get from HttpResponseMessage has status as :  WaitingForActivation
Can you please help me? What is the problem and why I don't get the record created in my instance?

the command I ran is in below (I only replaced myInstance.salesforce.com and token with correct values) :

curl -v https://myInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"Name" : "test_record1"}"

Comment: Have you tried changing the version to the latest (v45.0) and see if that works?

Comment: which software version you are talking about Das?

Comment: The API version as in the URL (.../v20.0/sobjects/...), instead of `v20.0`, have you tried with `v45.0`?

Comment: Yes I just tried with v45.0, same issue.

Comment: Have you tried from a different client, say POSTMAN?

Comment: No. I want to know if there is a way for a 3rd party application to make an API call to Salesforce and create an account for a customer inside Salesforce? So I am not quite sure the above instruction link I mentioned does what I want.

Comment: It is possible. And the link that you have referred is valid. It's just not clear as what issue you may be experiencing here.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes need to be escaped properly. The problem is with this bit:

```
"{"Name" : "test_record1"}"
```

This causes the shell to treat the quotes wrong. The following change should work:

```
"{\"Name\" : \"test_record1\"}"
```

Also, instead of dealing with escapes, you can also just make a file:

```
curl -v https://myInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json
```

Where payload.json is the name of the file you want to send.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, I see your point, but problem is still there. So I get no error but no record got created. I have tried with both "{\"Name\" : \"test_record1\"}"  passing straight in command line and also having "{"Name" : "test_record1"}" in a json file and passing the json file in command line.